# Part of logarithmic plot missing in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am using matplotlib to plot the current IC over the voltage VAC [see values below] and plotting in linear axis works perfectly fine:

[image: linear plot]

But when using instead of plt.plot plt.semilogy the following happens:

[image: logarithmic plot]

Dont know why there is some part of curve missing, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import struct as stc
plt.semilogy(VAC,IA) #first one uses plt.plot
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

IA=['0.3112E-04', '0.7237E-06', '0.1667E-07', '0.3896E-09', '0.0000E+00', '-0.1358E-12', '0.7944E-13', '0.4032E-12', '-0.2565E-13', '0.4066E-12', '0.0000E+00', '0.3893E-09', '0.1198E-08', '0.3699E-08', '0.1667E-07', '0.5165E-07', '0.1601E-06', '0.7237E-06', '0.2243E-05', '0.6943E-05', '0.3112E-04', '0.9462E-04', '0.2795E-03', '0.1081E-02', '0.2711E-02', '0.6283E-02', '0.1754E-01', '0.3596E-01', '0.7095E-01', '0.1638E+00', '0.2868E+00', '0.4603E+00', '0.4930E+00']

VAC=['0.6000E+00', '0.5000E+00', '0.4000E+00', '0.3000E+00', '0.0000E+00', '-0.4000E+00', '-0.7000E+00', '-0.1000E+01', '-0.7000E+00', '-0.4000E+00', '0.0000E+00', '0.3000E+00', '0.3300E+00', '0.3600E+00', '0.4000E+00', '0.4300E+00', '0.4600E+00', '0.5000E+00', '0.5300E+00', '0.5600E+00', '0.6000E+00', '0.6300E+00', '0.6600E+00', '0.7000E+00', '0.7300E+00', '0.7600E+00', '0.8000E+00', '0.8300E+00', '0.8600E+00', '0.9000E+00', '0.9300E+00', '0.9600E+00', '0.1000E+01']
```

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: So it is voltage vs time or current vs voltage? Also the values aren't really strings as you show them, I assume?

Comment: It looks like at least one of your y values is zero.  You can't take the log of zero, so zero values won't appear on the graph.

Comment: current vs voltage, labeling is wrong; values are of course numbers, I got it, its like you said the zero values AND negative values, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it, it was the negative values, which you cannot put into log(x).